# DFS Graph Pathfinding Giving Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, graph, path-finding

this is a homework assignment and I am attempting to find a path between start vertex v and end vertex u. I was provided with a test class to test the method and unfortunately I'm getting Null Pointer Exceptions.

Are there any obvious errors with my methods?

Thanks!

```
    public Iterator<Vertex<V>> returnPath(Graph<V> g, Vertex<V> v, Vertex<V> u){
    Iterator<Vertex<V>> result;
    Iterator<Edge<V>> it;
    Edge<V> e;
    Vertex<V> w;

    v.setMarker(true);
    S.push(v);
    if(v.equals(u)){
        return S.listIterator();
    }
    it = v.incidentEdges();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        e = it.next();
        w = g.giveOpposite(v, e);
        if(!w.getMarker()){
            result = returnPath(g, w, u);
            if(result != null){
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    S.pop();
    return null;
}

public Iterator<Vertex<V>> givePath(Graph<V> g, Vertex<V> v, Vertex<V> u){
    S.clear();
    return returnPath(g, v, u);
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at TestPath.main(TestPath.java:107)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

This if statement is 107:

```
Iterator<Vertex<Integer>> it = fp.givePath(g,lookup.elementAt(i),lookup.elementAt(j));
               if ( !it.hasNext() ){
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: @StinePike added!

Comment: So the problem is in some other part of your code... post the code where you have called this method

Answer (score 0):

You can refer my [code](https://github.com/OtakuAndFitness/Algorithm/blob/master/graphSearch.java) to implement DFS algorithm.